# Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element or Component. This means it will render an <Outlet /> React-router react version 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router

Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element or Component. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

The homepage to my react app is rendering an empty page could someone tell me what the issue is. Here's the code to my homepage.js where I believe the issue might be at

```
import React, { Component, useEffect} from "react";
import RoomJoinPage from "./RoomJoinPage";
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateRoomPage";
import Room from "./Room";
import { Grid, Button, ButtonGroup, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Info from "./Info";

export default class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      roomCode: null,
    };
    this.clearRoomCode = this.clearRoomCode.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/api/user-in-room")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          roomCode: data.code,
        });
      });
  }

  renderHomePage() {
    return (
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12} align="center">
          <Typography variant="h3" compact="h3">
            Lava Latte Soundscapes
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} align="center">
          <ButtonGroup disableElevation variant="contained" color="primary">
            <Button color="primary" to="/join" element={<Link/>}>
              Join a Room
            </Button>
            <Button color="default" to="/info" element={<Link/>}>
              Info
            </Button>
            <Button color="secondary" to="/create" element={<Link/>}>
              Create a Room
            </Button>
          </ButtonGroup>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
    
  }

  clearRoomCode() {
    this.setState({
      roomCode: null,
    });
  }  
  
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
        <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => {
              return this.state.roomCode ? (
                <Redirect to={`/room/${this.state.roomCode}`} />
              ) : (
                this.renderHomePage()
              );
            }}
          />
          
          <Route
            path="/room/:roomCode"
            render={(props) => {
              return <Room {...props} leaveRoomCallback={this.clearRoomCode} />;
            }}
          />

        </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

I looked up the issue and ended up trying this but it did not workout as I'd expected:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...

const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
  if (this.state.roomCode) {
    navigate(`/room/${this.state.roomCode}`);
  }
}, [this.state.roomCode, navigate]);

// ...

<Route path="/" element={this.state.roomCode ? <></> : this.renderHomePage()} />`
```